# Angular calling rest api infinitely

Tags: javascript, spring, angular

Using spring for backend. 
The aim is to get image by id and show the image in page.

I am receiving allItemsData from a rest api which contains the json sample

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "itemTitle": "'title'",
        "itemDescription": "desccription",
        "userDetails": {
            "name": "adminnew",
            "email": "user2@gmail.com",
            "user_role_id": 1
        },
        "categoryId": 0,
        "imageDetailsList": [
            {
                "id": 87,
                "imageLocation": "C:\\imagePath\\faviconxR0.47460100811443706.ico"
            },
            {
                "id": 88,
                "imageLocation": "C:\\imagePath\\faviconxR0.47460100811443702.ico"
            }
        ]
    },....]
```

Angular Code shown below

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of allItemsData">
          <td>{{data.id}}</td>
          <td>{{data.itemTitle}}</td>
          <td>{{data.itemDescription}}</td>
          <td>{{data.userDetails.name}}</td>          
          <td>
            <table class='table table-striped'>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>                
                <th>image</th>
                <th>imageLocation</th>
              </tr>
              <tr *ngFor="let imageData of data.imageDetailsList">
                <td>{{imageData.id}}</td>
                <td><img [src]="getImage(imageData.id)></td>
                <td>{{imageData.imageLocation}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

When getImageData() is invoked the client will execute rest api to fetch Image data(Blob) from Spring based server.The problem is image api is getting called infinitely. If I execute getImageData in constructor it will execute only two times.

1. What is the reason behind it?
2. Please mention any other alternate angular way or rest api design

Comment: thats how data binding works, it constantly checks for the latest data

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon!

Its object is calling the getImageData () function on each iterated item in the data array.

The problem is that the Angular makes constant checks to detect changes and thus update the information for the user. The contructor () runs when the component is initialized and this does not happen again.

My suggestion (since I'm not seeing your controller) is: Use a service to make your API request, then use the RxJS operators to properly populate the image. Example:

```
this.myService.getData().pipe(
    map(data => {
        data.imageDetailsList.map(item => {
            // item.id - Apply your logic to get the image correctly here, be sure to iterate a new array and return it so that the call returns the expected result.
        })
    })
)
```